# How to implement filter or search in react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new in react-redux.

**Scenario**: On app load, I fetch a list of 10 items from backend to redux. Now say, I apply a filter, which fetches result from redux and shows 3 items, but backend still have 10 more items. Then how do I show those 10 items ?

Should I fetch data from api whenever user applies a filter ? If yes, then what's the benefit of redux here ?

Comment: When you say the backend still has 10 more items, are those the original 10 items that you fetched or 10 new items to fetch?

Comment: 10 new items... to be fetched after applying filter.  Backend have 100 items.. i fetched 10 items initially... then i apply filter which filters those 10 items and shows 3 items.... but this is incomplete result for the user... as there is more items based on that filter in dabase but not in redux.

Comment: 10 new items.. For ex. I have 100 users in database. I fetched 10 users initially, (rest 90 users will be shown on scrolling or pagination.)  I apply a filter say.. users with age 25. This results 3 users with 25 age. But the result is from redux so its incomplete.
 rest 90 users are not filtered here. How do I show results from those 90 users too...?

Answer (score 1):

**Redux is a predictable state container for JavaScript apps**, so lets say you have 10 components that need to use your data in one way or another; one to count the total, the other to show the last 5 etc... with redux you just update your state from any point and all components behave to the change.

**Scenario one**: Facebook has a component that shows a list of messages and another component that shows the list of your unread messages and another component where next to the friend that just messaged you there is a badge that says new message... instead of each component having to fetch these data separately with redux you can fetch everything once and pass it on to the right place.

**Scenario two**: lets say one of your components have a input field and once you write a message in it you want your other components to react in some way. with redux you just pass the data into your reducer and it gets delegated in all your components.

**How to implement filter or search in react-redux?**

And to answer your question, it really depends on the type and size of your application but I usually implement the filter in component rather than in reducer.

Comment: I understand your concept about redux.. bt my question is.. I have total 10 items say users in redux and shows 3  users out of 10 after applying filter...(by implementing filter in component)....its fast....but its not complete result as database has more users for that filter which are not is redux yet. Then how would I show those more users from backend.... ?

Comment: if your question is about how to load data : I usually dispatch action that loads data in componentDidMount and once they are in my reducer I don't mutate them. so my reducer have 10 users and I'll just display 3.

Comment: If your reducer has 10 users and I apply a filter which filtet users according to name initials with P,  this will show result out of those 10 only.  But there are 100 users in backend. I want results from there too.

Comment: so your question is, how would it work if you have 1 million users and fetch the last 10 from database initially, then filter by surname `smith` with no limit.

Comment: If so that's not a redux job, redux job is to help all your component behaved/interact with the same data... you need to deal with that in API level, look up GraphQL if you want to be cool :)

Comment: well.. if I have to call api for each filter then why shows e.g  like visibility filter using reselect. Or Would i have to maintain a sparate list of user for each filter instead of having a common list o users for app.